# Reference aliased field in QueryDSL

Tags: sql, subquery, alias, querydsl

I have the following query in QueryDSL:

```
Expression<?>[] projection = {
    table.field1.as("field1"),
    table.field2.as("field2")
};

SQLSubQuery subquery = new SQLSubQuery()
    .from(table)
    .where(...);

NumberPath<BigDecimal> field1 = new NumberPath<BigDecimal>(BigDecimal.class, "field1");
DateTimePath<Timestamp> field2 = new DateTimePath<Timestamp>(Timestamp.class, "field2");

SQLSubQuery query = new SQLSubQuery()
    .from(table, subquery.list(projection))
    .where(table.field1.eq(field1).and(table.field2.eq(field2)))
    .groupBy(contentcache1.programId, contentcache1.id);
```

I'm trying to reference the aliased fields in the subquery (field1 and field2) in the main query. Unfortunately, I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Undeclared path 'field1'. Add this path as a source to the query to be able to reference it.
    at com.mysema.query.types.ValidatingVisitor.visit(ValidatingVisitor.java:65)
    at com.mysema.query.types.ValidatingVisitor.visit(ValidatingVisitor.java:27)
    at com.mysema.query.types.path.NumberPath.accept(NumberPath.java:53)
    at com.mysema.query.types.ValidatingVisitor.visit(ValidatingVisitor.java:119)
    at com.mysema.query.types.ValidatingVisitor.visit(ValidatingVisitor.java:53)
    at com.mysema.query.types.ValidatingVisitor.visit(ValidatingVisitor.java:27)
    at com.mysema.query.types.expr.BooleanOperation.accept(BooleanOperation.java:53)
    at com.mysema.query.types.ValidatingVisitor.visit(ValidatingVisitor.java:119)
    at com.mysema.query.types.ValidatingVisitor.visit(ValidatingVisitor.java:53)
    at com.mysema.query.types.ValidatingVisitor.visit(ValidatingVisitor.java:27)
    at com.mysema.query.types.expr.BooleanOperation.accept(BooleanOperation.java:53)
    at com.mysema.query.types.ValidatingVisitor.visit(ValidatingVisitor.java:87)
    at com.mysema.query.types.ValidatingVisitor.visit(ValidatingVisitor.java:27)
    at com.mysema.query.types.query.ListSubQuery.accept(ListSubQuery.java:69)
    at com.mysema.query.DefaultQueryMetadata.validate(DefaultQueryMetadata.java:318)
    at com.mysema.query.DefaultQueryMetadata.addJoin(DefaultQueryMetadata.java:112)
    at com.mysema.query.DefaultQueryMetadata.addJoin(DefaultQueryMetadata.java:102)
    at com.mysema.query.support.QueryMixin.from(QueryMixin.java:143)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.AbstractSQLQuery.from(AbstractSQLQuery.java:67)
    at com.irtve.plataforma.api.service.dsl.impl.AssetManagerImpl.findAllFirstInProgram(AssetManagerImpl.java:466)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy51.findAllFirstInProgram(Unknown Source)
    at com.irtve.plataforma.bms.model.multimedia.video.VideoRepositoryImpl.findAllFirstInProgram(VideoRepositoryImpl.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy83.findAllFirstInProgram(Unknown Source)
    at com.irtve.plataforma.bms.model.multimedia.video.VideosProgramasServiceImpl.findAllFirstInProgram(VideosProgramasServiceImpl.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy105.findAllFirstInProgram(Unknown Source)
    at com.irtve.plataforma.rest.service.multimedias.videosprogramas.delegate.VideosProgramasServiceDelegate.findAll(VideosProgramasServiceDelegate.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor$1.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:213)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy195.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.irtve.plataforma.rest.service.multimedias.videosprogramas.VideosProgramasServiceFacadeImpl.findAll(VideosProgramasServiceFacadeImpl.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor$1.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:213)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy196.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.irtve.plataforma.rest.service.multimedias.videosprogramas.controller.VideosProgramasController.findAll(VideosProgramasController.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.CachingFilter.buildPage(CachingFilter.java:302)
    at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.SimpleCachingHeadersPageCachingFilter.buildPage(SimpleCachingHeadersPageCachingFilter.java:120)
    at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.CachingFilter.buildPageInfo(CachingFilter.java:247)
    at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.CachingFilter.doFilter(CachingFilter.java:216)
    at com.irtve.plataforma.rest.cache.RestCacheFilter.doFilter(RestCacheFilter.java:87)
    at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat60AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat60AgentValve.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I've also tried the following:

```
SSTable aliasedTable = new SSTable("AliasedTable");

SQLSubQuery subquery = new SQLSubQuery()
    .from(aliasedTable)
    .where(...);

NumberPath<BigDecimal> field1 = new NumberPath<BigDecimal>(BigDecimal.class, "field1");
DateTimePath<Timestamp> field2 = new DateTimePath<Timestamp>(Timestamp.class, "field2");

SQLSubQuery query = new SQLSubQuery()
    .from(table, subquery.list(projection))
    .where(table.field1.eq(aliasedTable.field1).and(table.field2.eq(aliasedTable.field2)))
    .groupBy(contentcache1.programId, contentcache1.id);
```

But I'm getting the same error but "AliasedTable" instead of "field1".

How could I reference an aliased field from an outter select?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
SSTable table2 = new SSTable("table2");

SQLSubQuery subquery = new SQLSubQuery()
    .from(table2)
    .where(...);

SQLSubQuery query = new SQLSubQuery()
    .from(table, subquery.list(projection).as(table2))
    .where(table.field1.eq(table2.field1), table.field2.eq(table2.field2))
    .groupBy(contentcache1.programId, contentcache1.id);
```

Comment: I tried it as I shown in my original post, but it doesn't work, I don't know why

Comment: Oh, I see, I needed to add ".as(table2)" in my original query.

Answer (score 1):

I finally did it using Expression templates:

```
NumberExpression<BigDecimal> field1 = Expressions.numberTemplate(BigDecimal.class, "field1");
DateTimeExpression<Timestamp> field2 = DateTimeTemplate.create(Timestamp.class, "field2");

SQLSubQuery query = new SQLSubQuery()
    .from(table, subquery.list(projection))
    .where(table.field1.eq(field1).and(table.field2.eq(field2)))
    .groupBy(contentcache1.programId, contentcache1.id);
```

**UPDATE**

Although I did it in this way, Timo's was a better and cleaner solution.